# Bug in random array generator

Tags: java, arrays, random, generator

Could you please advise why this random array generator method works if array size is set to be smaller than range of values numbers can take, but it does not work otherwise. For example method works if `n = 10` and `max = 100`. But it does not return anything if `n = 10` and `max = 5`.

Also, could somebody please explain why `boolean` `markDup` variable is used here?

Thanks in advance for insights.

```
public static int[] getRandomArray(int n, int max) {
        Random random = new Random();
        int[] randomArray = new int[n];
        for (int j = 0; j < n;) {

            int randomNumber = random.nextInt(max - 1);

            boolean markDup = false;
            for (int indexRandomArray = 0; indexRandomArray < n; indexRandomArray++) {
                if (randomArray[indexRandomArray] == randomNumber) {
                    markDup = true;
                    break;
                }
            }

            if (!markDup) {
                randomArray[j] = randomNumber;
                j++;
            }

        }

        for(int x:randomArray) System.out.print(x+" "); 
        System.out.println(); 
        return randomArray;
    }
```

Answer (score 3):

If `n` is `10` and `max` is `5` then you will end up with an infinite loop.

After producing the 'random' numbers 0, 1, 2 and 3 every subsequently generated number will be marked as a duplicate.

When `markDup` is always `true`, `j++` is never executed.

Comment: actually, the generated numbers will be 0..3

Answer (score 2):

It's obvious, you're checking if numbers are duplicate in this line  `if (!markDup) {`, of course when you set a max that is smaller than your array size, will never fill the whole array because that are no sufficient numbers and `j` will never be increased, so the loop will run indefinitely

Answer (score 0):

Here is a fixed version (Would not run this in production, randomness is pretty weak)

```
public class Test {

    public static int[] getRandomArray(int n, int max, boolean allowDups) {

        if (!allowDups && n > max) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        }

        Random random = new Random();
        int[] randomArray = new int[n];
        outer: for (int j = 0; j < n;) {

            int randomNumber = random.nextInt(max - 1);

            if (!allowDups) {
                for (int indexRandomArray = 0; indexRandomArray < j; indexRandomArray++) {
                    if (randomArray[indexRandomArray] == randomNumber) {
                        continue outer;
                    }
                }
            }

            randomArray[j] = randomNumber;
            j++;

        }

        for (int x : randomArray)
            System.out.print(x + " ");
        System.out.println();
        return randomArray;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        getRandomArray(10, 5, true);
        getRandomArray(9, 10, false);
        getRandomArray(10, 100, false);
        getRandomArray(5, 1000, false);
    }
}
```